# Change product price before putting it on a cart

Tags: ubercart

**Overview:**

I have a website that only sells **one** product. It has a $0.00 Price.

I have this custom form when sent, it will give the product id (e.g.) to the uc_cart_add_item

```
uc_cart_add_item($nid, $qty = 1, $data = NULL, $cid = NULL, $msg = TRUE, $check_redirect = TRUE, $rebuild = TRUE);
```

Well, technically it goes to the cart with a price of $0.00.

So the question here is, how can I alter the product price before sending it to the cart?

I saw this function from other website that this one alters the product price

```
hook_uc_product_alter(&$node)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work or something.

I've searched for some questions

[Ubercart alter product price when product added to cart](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57608/ubercart-alter-product-price-when-product-added-to-cart)

Even this one, but it's on Drupal Commerce not on Ubercart

[programmically change price of product](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97303/programmically-change-price-of-product)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to alter the *cart item*, not the product node. `hook_uc_cart_alter` is what you're looking for.

```
function MYMODULE_uc_cart_alter(&$items) {
  foreach($items as $key => $item) { //Set all items to $3.50
    $item->price = 3.50;
  }
}
```

Comment: I saw this code somewhere (that looks like this) and I tried it and it does not work for some reason, and yet I tried this it work. Oh my. Thanks for this! xD